# How to delete CloudFormation stack with an RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

To reproduce:

1. Create a CloudFormation stack containing an RDS instance.
2. Attempt to delete the stack with

   ```bash
   aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name=[stack name]
   aws cloudformation wait stack-delete-complete --stack-name=[stack name]
   ```
3. Once the second command returns `DELETE_FAILED` check the stack events list to find this message:

   > One or more database instances are still members of this parameter group […], so the group cannot be deleted
4. Manually force deletion of the database instance with

   ```
   aws rds delete-db-instance --db-instance-identifier=[DB physical ID] --skip-final-snapshot
   aws rds wait db-instance-deleted --db-instance-identifier=[DB physical ID]
   ```
5. Repeat step 2.
6. Once the second command returns `DELETE_FAILED` check the stack events list to find these messages:

   > Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.

   and

   > The following resource(s) failed to delete: [DB logical ID].

Now what? The secret and DB are gone, but the stack can't be deleted.

Last time this happened I was told by AWS Support to simply wait until the stack "caught up" with the fact that the database instance was deleted, but that's not ideal as it takes more than 12 hours.

Sort of relevant: [How do I delete an AWS CloudFormation stack that's stuck in DELETE_FAILED status?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-delete-failed/)

Comment: I can't help you fix your problem because I'd have to see the stack in question.  But one thing you should take from this , is that cloudformation _keeps its own state_ of the resources, and if you delete them outside cloudformation, it's likely to make bigger messes.

Comment: Show us the exact template you're deploying

Comment: @Paolo I can't give you the entire template/stack info, because this is an internal application.

Comment: Well then create a new template in order to provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @erik258 CloudFormation *forces* me to delete the resource manually, though, so there's a catch-22.

Comment: " CloudFormation forces me to delete the resource manually" no it doesn't.  you're doing it wrong.  Look closely at the errors.  The error you posted says the parameter group can't be deleted because an instance was using it.  you went and deleted an instance.  In your case you might be setting the DeletionPolicy for the RDS instance to Retain in your stack but I certanly can't conclude that from what you've chosen to share.

Comment: It's got `DeletionPolicy: Snapshot`

Comment: @erik258 I mean, no part of the error message tells me what to do next, so I did the obvious thing and deleted the thing the stack deletion command refused to delete. I just want the whole stack gone, no ands, ifs, or buts.

Comment: @Paolo I'm afraid it would take many hours, if not days, to tear down the template to something minimal, especially since I'm not a CloudFormation expert. I thought maybe the commands and error messages might be enough to work out the underlying issue.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you if you don't provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: "One or more database instances are still members of this parameter group […], so the group cannot be deleted" how does that lead you to think you needed to delete a database instance?

Comment: Because if I delete the DB instance there would no longer be anything blocking the deletion of the parameter group.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same situation as you describe. I was able to successfully delete the stack by:

1. Deleting the CloudFormation stack in the console while clicking the checkbox to retain the resource of the database cluster/instance. This allows the deletion to succeed while skipping this resource which should already be deleted.

A slightly different sequence of steps that seems to behave more smoothly is:

1. if you first manually delete all the instance (readers first then writers) and then DBCluster (if applicable)
2. you should then be able to delete the CloudFormation stack smoothly.

Based on the AWS documentation it seems there are some guardrails in place around deleting Aurora RDS instances, [AuroraUserGuide/USER_DeleteCluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_DeleteCluster.html).